# How to break inside a generator?

Tags: python, list, loops, generator

```
    def permutationEquation(p):
        result=[]
        for i in range(1,len(p)+1):
            result.append(list(y+1 for y,v in enumerate(p) if(p[v-1]==i)))
```

How to break once if condition is satisfied.
and i dont to want do with a another for loop,i want the code to be simple.
and how to make result list a single dimension.
now the list is [[1],[2],[3]]
i want it as [1,2,3]

Comment: It's impossible to stop a generator. You can only stop _consuming_ it (it's a huge hint that should make you google that).

Comment: post your input `p` value

Comment: permutation is a simple list

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a good use for a generator.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman why?

Comment: Well, mainly because you can't break and you can't get a flat list...

Comment: You can simply use `next()` instead of `list()`, and you will get the desired result.

Comment: @Sven Marnach can you be more specific?

Comment: There is one occurrence of the word `list` in your code.  Delete that and write `next` instead.

Comment: I should add that this isn't the best way to solve your problem.  It's just the minimal change to your code to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps `result.extend(y+1 for y,v in enumerate(p) if(p[v-1]==i))`.  That changes `append()` to `extend()` and since `extend()` accepts an iterator it gets rid of the call to `list()`.  (Of course it's still inefficient.)

Comment: You can have `enumerate` start with 1 instead of 0; that will probably simplify a lot of your index wrangling.

Comment: Provide a sample input and the expected output.

Comment: If you want to break an iterator use `itertools.takewhile`.

Comment: @chepner [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/permutation-equation/problem)

Comment: @chepner To simplify the index wrangling, the elements of the permutation should simply be 0, 1, …, n-1 – then we can get rid of _all_ the additions and subtractions of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input `p` is a permutation, then what your function is computing is `p` to the power of -2, or the square of the inverse of the permutation.  This can be computed in linear time (linear in the size of the permutation), whereas your code uses quadratic time.

I also suggest to use the numbers 0, 1, …, n-1 in the permutation, since this meshes much nicer with Python's 0-based indexing.  When using these simpler numbers, here's a simpler function to solve your problem:

```
def permutationEquation(p):
    inv = [None] * len(p)
    for i, x in enumerate(p):
        inv[x] = i
    return [inv[x] for x in inv]
```

Comment: I was trying to do this [Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/permutation-equation/problem) in hackerank. I dont this your solution fits in.It causes index out of range error.

Comment: @ShashiTunga As I mentioned in the answer, you need to adjust the indices to be zero-based, so you need to subtract one from every integer you read in, and add one again when printing the results.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy, you just have to translate it into a `for` loop.

The fact that you don't want a for loop is something you're just going to have to deal with.

```
def permutationEquation(p):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(p)+1):
        for y, v in enumerate(p):
            if p[v-1] != i:
                break
            result.append(y + 1)
```

Comment: Looks to me like this satisfies *both* OP's requirements of breaking and not a list of lists.